# Spring + Hibernate DBCP long transaction JDBC Commit Failed

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc

i have an production issue regarding Spring + Hibernate application that keep throwing JDBC Commit Failed in certain of time (intermittent, sometime it take a month, but sometimes 2-4 times a month to get this error). i don't know how to reproduce the issue. i'm using Oracle database, Hibernate Framework and DBCP Connection pool:

here it is the stack trace:

```
[16:05:22,993] http-8443-110 ERROR JDBCTransaction:? [6281213202858-20160804160022875-817604] - JDBC commit failed
java.sql.SQLException: Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@5125aa4f is closed.
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.checkOpen(DelegatingConnection.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:334)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:211)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$ConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:178)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:271)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy362.commit(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commitAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:146)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy296.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.mfino.transactionapi.service.impl.AccountAPIServicesImpl.handleRequest(AccountAPIServicesImpl.java:308)
    at com.mfino.webapi.servlet.WebApiRequestController.processWebAPITransactions(WebApiRequestController.java:287)
    at com.mfino.webapi.servlet.WebApiRequestController.getHttpsRequest(WebApiRequestController.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor425.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:206)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Anybody face the same issue? Please Help,

Comment: Could it be that you're connecting to a RAC database and some of the instances are brought down for maintenance?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. but it only one instance and the database guy said that there are no issue with the database, they have check the log, but found no error,